# Homomorphism between diedral group $D_3$ triangle isometries and $S_3$ identification problem

Tags: group-theory

My question deals with the dihedral group $D_3$ of equilateral triangle 123 (1 top vertex, 2 bottom right vertex, 3 bottom left vertex).

- R1 is the counterclockwise rotation of 120 degrees.
- R2 is the counterclockwise rotation of 240 degrees.
- SA is the symmetry through the top angle bissectrice (exchanging vertex 2 and 3)
- SB is the symmetry through the right angle bissectrice (exchanging vertex 1 and 3)
- SC is the symmetry through the left angle bisssectrice (exchanging  vertex 1 and 2)

I constructed the Cayley table accordingly, and compared it to the $S_3$ Cayley table: they match very well, hence my deduction that:

- R1 matches with permutation (123) of $S_3$.
- R2 matches with permutation (321).
- SA matches with permutation (23).
- SB matches with permutation (12).
- SC matches with permutation (31).

First question, is this correspondence fully right? The shapes of the two tables are quite similar, but I did not try all the possibilities.

Second problem :

I tried to deepen the above correspondence as follows :

If I write a symmetry in a line with 1st figure = top vertex, 2nd figure = right vertex and 3rd figure = left vertex, the symmetry R1 can be written

Answer (score 1):

One way to prove the isomorphism is the following (this seems to be what your are trying to do in your second question):

The group $S_3$ acts on the set with three points. If you number the vertices of an equilateral triangle 1,2 and 3 then you can see that $S_3$ acts on your triangle. Looking at the action of $S_3$ on your triangle, you can see that you get *all* of the symmetries of the triangle. As the group of symmetries of the triangle is precisely $D_3$, you are done!$^{\dagger}$

You should realise that this isomorphism is precisely the one you found by looking at the Cayley tables. So your correspondence is correct.

---

$^{\dagger}$Well, actually this just shows that there is a surjective homomorphism $S_3\rightarrow D_3$. Do you understand why this implies that there is an isomorphism between these groups?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the subgroup $H:=\{\texttt{1},\texttt{SA}\}$. Now:
\begin{alignat}{1}
\texttt{R1.SA.R1}^{-1} &=  \texttt{R1.SA.R2} \\
&= \texttt{SB} \\
&\ne \texttt{SA} \\
\end{alignat}
whence: $$H\cap(\texttt{R1.}H\texttt{.R1}^{-1})=\{\texttt{1}\}$$
This suffices to conclude that $D_3$ acts faithfully by left multiplication on the left quotient set $D_3/H$, namely:
$$D_3\hookrightarrow S_{D_3/H}\cong S_3$$
But both $D_3$ and $S_3$ have cardinality $6$, hence actually:
$$D_3\cong S_3$$
(Incidentally, this basically proves that $D_n\hookrightarrow S_n$ for every $n>2$.)